# Equivalent code from python apply function to Pyspark code using udf

Tags: python, string, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
            (1, "AxtTR"),  # create your data here, be consistent in the types.
            (2, "HdyOP"),
            (3, "EqoPIC"),
            (4, "OkTEic"),
        ], ["id", "label"] )# add your column names here]
df.show()
```

Below code is in python , where i use apply function and tried extracting first 2 letters of every  row. i want to replicate the same code in pyspark. where a function is used to apply on every single row and get the output.

```
def get_string(lst):    
    lst = str(lst)
    lst = lst.lower
    lst=  lst[0:2]
    return(lst)
df['firt_2letter'] = df['label'].apply(get_string)
```

The yellow marked as shown in below image is the expected output.

[image: Expected Output & data frame]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the relevant Spark SQL functions:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('first_2letter', F.lower('label')[0:2])

df2.show()
+---+------+-------------+
| id| label|first_2letter|
+---+------+-------------+
|  1| AxtTR|           ax|
|  2| HdyOP|           hd|
|  3|EqoPIC|           eq|
|  4|OkTEic|           ok|
+---+------+-------------+
```

If you want to use user-defined functions, you can define them as:

```
def get_string(lst):    
    lst = str(lst)
    lst = lst.lower()
    lst = lst[0:2]
    return lst

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('first_2letter', F.udf(get_string)('label'))

df2.show()
+---+------+-------------+
| id| label|first_2letter|
+---+------+-------------+
|  1| AxtTR|           ax|
|  2| HdyOP|           hd|
|  3|EqoPIC|           eq|
|  4|OkTEic|           ok|
+---+------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thank you , just wanted to know this is simple function. If there is a customize how we can call that function in pyspark

Comment: one more query , if in case we are passing two column def get_string(vec):    lst = vec[0];lst1 =  vec[1]
    lst = str(lst)
    lst = lst.lower()
    lst = lst[0:2]
    return lst , In suct case df.withColumn('first_2letter', F.udf(get_string)(['col1','col2'])). is this the correct method ?

Comment: then add one more argument to the function